# query on python function- two square brackets in function

Tags: python

I saw this function. Can someone pls explain the purpose of putting two square brackets

```
def min_max(row):
    data = row[['POPESTIMATE2010',
                'POPESTIMATE2011',
                'POPESTIMATE2012',
                'POPESTIMATE2013',
                'POPESTIMATE2014',
                'POPESTIMATE2015']]
    row['max'] = np.max(data)
    row['min'] = np.min(data)
    return row
```

Comment: Does the answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Double Brackets refers to **[Nested List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions)**.

In short terms, consider this as **Matrix**, EG

```
>> matrix = [
...     [1, 2, 3, 4],
...     [5, 6, 7, 8],
...     [9, 10, 11, 12],
... ]
```